# Swift protocol extension not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I tried to make a default implementation of protocol `UIScrollViewDelegate`, for example:

```
extension UIScrollViewDelegate {
     func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         //...
     }
}
```

But In a subclass `UITableViewController` (which conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` and) does not contain any implementation this method (neither in base class nor in subclass), this extension-provided implementation won't be called

Is there any solution to provide a default implementation for these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a Swift protocol extension on an Objective-C protocol. That's never going to work, because Objective-C cannot *see* a Swift protocol extension, so Cocoa (which is Objective-C) will never know about your implementation and will never call it.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an extension of `UIScrollView` to conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol like this:

```
extension UIScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work though.